# How to make a button within a Link not trigger Link redirect

Tags: reactjs, button, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a div on my page that is rendered multiple times with different `teamObj`s. I make it redirect to the full page for that team using a `Link`.

```
 <div className="team-card" key={teamObj.id}>
    <Link to={`${this.props.links.teams + "/" + teamObj.id}`}>
      <div className="row no-gutter flex" style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
        <div className="col-sm-3 team-card-column">
            {this.renderTeamTitle(teamObj)}
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-9">
          <div className="row" style={{ margin: '0 auto' }}>
            {teamLogo ?
              <>
                <div className="col-8 team-card-column">
                  <TeamInfoBars teamStats={teamStats} />
                </div>
                <div className="col-4 team-card-column">
                  <img className='team-card-img' src={teamLogo.url} alt="" />
                </div>
              </>
              :
              <div className="team-card-column">
                <TeamInfoBars teamStats={teamStats} />
              </div>
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Link>
  </div >
```

Within `renderTeamTitle`, I display a button that lets the user join the team. The section of `renderTeamTitle` that renders this button is below:

```
<div className="col-3 col-sm-12">
      {(this.props.user && !this.inTeam(teamObj.id)) &&
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.joinTeam(teamObj);
          }}
          className="btn btn-success round-me join-team-btn-small raise"
        >
          Join
        </button>
      }
</div>
```

However, since this button is a child of the `Link`, clicking it triggers `joinTeam` as well as the `Link` redirect. Naturally, I don't want the button to do the latter behaviour. What would be the most elegant way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to stop all other events beside yours. This should do the trick:

```
onClick={event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.joinTeam(teamObj);
}}
```

Comment: Great! Just what I needed. I'll accept your answer once Stackoverfow lets me :)